# Use empty strings with AWS Amplify API and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I started to use AWS Amplify for a web app.

I configured AppSync GraphQL using a DynamoDB datasource as suggested by the [Getting Started tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start#step-3-add-api-and-database).

One of my values is an empty string and I get this error when trying to do an insert

```
"One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0000000SOMETHING0000000)"
```

It seems it can be solved by passing the option `convertEmptyValues: true` to the DynamoDB client. Do you know how I can pass a such option using AppSync ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found such an option in the Amplify codebase. I hope it will be added.

In the meantime, I pass my emptiable strings this way:

```
{
  id: id,
  title: title,
  description: description || null
}
```